# FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthorized() always returns false in Page_Load in IE

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have a asp.net page to check if the permission has been set by facebook user. But when the user setup the permission and go back to this page again, the FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthorized() still returns false in IE. When I reload the page again using F5, FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthorized() then returns true.

The value of FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthorized() are different when the page loads and after I manually reload the page.

The code is working correctly in FireFox and Chrome. Do you know why and how can I solve this problem?

Thank you very much!!!

=============================================================

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
            // enable third party cookies on IE
            Response.AppendHeader("P3P", "CP=\"CAO PSA OUR\"");

            IsAuthorized = FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthorized();


            if (IsAuthorized && !Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Response.Redirect("RegisterForm.aspx");
            }   

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, I found the root cause of this problem.

Facebook is using Cookies to track the permission setting of the facebook user. But sometimes the cookie cannot access by IE in the IFrame. To solve the problem, you should set P3P policy settings in your Page_Load handler.

```
Response.AppendHeader("P3P", "CP=\"CAO PSA OUR\"");
```

I think the better way to do it is to set P3P settings in the global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("p3p", "CP=\"CAO PSA OUR\"");

}
```

I tested my facebook application, and now it is working just fine.